# Measurement of glucose concentration in the human brain

Tags: biochemistry, neuroscience

If I want to measure the exact glucose concentration in a human brain then how can I proceed to do that? Is there any technique or assay to do that?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible by using <sup>13</sup>C NMR Spectroscopy.

It has been done after infusing enriched D-[1-<sup>13</sup>C]glucose in six healthy children. The results showed that at euglycemia glucose concentration is about 1 micromol/ml.

---

**Source:** Gruetter R, Novotny EJ, Boulware SD, Rothman DL, Mason GF, Shulman GI, Shulman RG, Tamborlane WV. [Direct measurement of brain glucose concentrations in humans by 13C NMR spectroscopy.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1736294) Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. U.S.A. 1992 Feb 1;89(3):1109-12. PubMed PMID: 1736294.